# How to use Pug on the server?

Tags: node.js, pug

Since I am always working on the server and not local, I am wondering if there is a way to use Pug (aka Jade) on the server. For now if I type `pug index.pug` on Node.js command prompt, I'll get an HTML file which gets stored on a local directory. Would it be possible to upload this file automatically on the FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pug compile and then get the html string. Write the HTML string in to a file using "FS" module to write in the local temp folder.

```
var fn = pug.compileFile(templatePath);
var html = fn(data);
fs.writeFile('test.html', html, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Then read the file from location and then send using the method mentioned here.
[How to send a file from remote URL as a GET response in Node.js Express app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288055/how-to-send-a-file-from-remote-url-as-a-get-response-in-node-js-express-app)