# Express res.redirect shows content but not downloads

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I have and API link what automatically starts downloading file if I follow it in address bar. Let's call it **my-third-party-downloading-link-com**.

But when in Express framework I set res.redirect(my-third-party-downloading-link-com). I get status code 301 and can see file content in **Preview tab** in developer tools. But I can't make Browser downloading this file.

My appropriate request handler is following:

```
downloadFeed(req, res) {
  const { jobId, platform, fileName } = req.query;
  const host = platform === 'production' ? configs.prodHost : 
  configs.stageHost;
  const downloadLink = `${host}/api/v1/feedfile/${jobId}`;

  // I also tried with these headers
  // res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; 
  //   filename=${fileName}.gz');
  // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-gzip');

  res.redirect(downloadLink)
}
```

**P.S** Now, to solve this problem, I build **my-third-party-downloading-link-com** on back-end, send it with res.end and then:

```
window.open(**my-third-party-downloading-link-com**, '_blank').
```

But I don't like this solution. How can I tell browser to start downloading content form this third-party API ?

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, you should use res.download() to force a browser to prompt the user for download.

http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.download

Comment: you are not right. We are speaking about third-party link, not about file on the server's file system.

Comment: ok, then you can check this other question, it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288055/how-to-send-a-file-from-remote-url-as-a-get-response-in-node-js-express-app